# Getting value of sent JSON value

Tags: json

I need to check if a certain key/value pair arrives in a Node application. The value of the key is typed in a input field in a angular application. I am a little stuck with this, can anybody help? Probably been staring at this too long...

```
var button_sendtext = JSON.stringify([{"key":"sendtext","value":" this will be a variable text "}])
if(message == button_sendtext) {
  request // do request to internal webserver
  .get('http://thisisjusttesturl/api', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      console.log(response);
      console.log(body);
    } else {
      console.log('Error!');
    }
  });
}
```

**UPDATE:**

The app I am making is partly a Kodi remote, the text I type in an input field is sent to the Kodi API via a broker. A `GET` request works, so that is not the problem. The node application needs to interpret what text is being sent via the app. Right now, I am checking fixed keys and values. Hopefully this clarifies things...

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `post` to send JSON to server?

Comment: Do you want Node or Angular? If it's Angular, then what do you have in a service/factory and what do you have in the controller? If it's a Node question, then add the tag 'node.js' not 'angular'.

Comment: I'm confused as to what the issue is... What is the problem? And that url looks wrong.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I shouldn't have tagged Angular. It's mostly a node question. The app i am making is partly a Kodi remote, the text i type in an input field is send to the Kodi API via a broker. A get request works, so that is not the problem. The node application needs to interpret what text is being sent via the app. Right now, i am checking fixed keys and values. Hopefully this clarifies things...

Answer (score 0):

I've been busting my brains all days for this. This is how i solved it:

```
var button_sendtext = message;
function stringStartsWith (string, prefix) {
  return string.slice(0, prefix.length) == prefix;
}
if(stringStartsWith(button_sendtext, '[{"key":"sendtext"')) {
```